# I have to send these the variables into the class under: String navn, double pris, double virkestoff

Tags: java, class, variables, constructor

I tried this, but that doesnt work.

```
class Legemiddel{
public static void main(String navn, double pris, double virkestoff){
String navnet=navn;
double prisen=pris;
double virkestoffet=virkestoff;}}
```

Since I have to make the constructor like this:

```
class Legemiddel{
public static void main(String[] args){}}
```

So how to I get the variables into the class,when I send it from another class like this.

```
class TestLegemiddel{
public static void main(String[] args){
Legemiddel legemiddel=new Legemiddel("Ibuton", 212.99, 30.5);}}
```

The answer below worked, but I get a new problem when creating subclasses that extends the class Legemiddel. I did this

```
class LegemiddelA extends Legemiddel{    
private int styrke;
public LegemiddelA(int styrke){
this.styrke=styrke;}
public int hentNarkotiskStyrke(){    
return styrke;}}
```

But I get this

legemiddel.java:31: error: constructor Legemiddel in class Legemiddel cannot be applied to given types;
  public LegemiddelA(int styrke){
                                ^
  required: String,double,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You already tagged this "constructor". What can you do inside the constructor?

Comment: I dont know what I can do inside the constructor to take in the variables

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor that accepts these three values so that you can pass them from the `main` method. Also you need fields to assing these values to.

```
class Legemiddel {
  private String name;
  private double price;
  private double virkestoff;

  public Legemiddel(String name, double price, double virkestoff) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.virkestoff = virkestoff;
  }
}
```

The call

```
new Legemiddel("Ibuton", 212.99, 30.5);
```

creates an instance of `Legemiddel` and initalizes it's fields with the constructor's argument values.